# No good answer today for Angular ngIf async/observable state change bug

Tags: angular, state, onchange, angular-ng-if

Googling around it seems just about anyone who's ever dabbled in Angular has had this issue before :

you make a Dom element with an `*ngIf` directive :

```
<div *ngIf="array.length">
Don't show me until I'm ready please !
</div>
```

You have an eval on the spot for whether the child dom should exist.

then, for example, you receive your data as an api response :

```
 this.http.post(
      this.url,
      args,
      this.authenticationService.getRequestOptions()
    ).subscribe(data => {
        this.array = data;
        console.log('truthy? : ', this.array.length);
    }
 );
```

for some reason the Angular change detect fails at this point and the `*ngIf` Dom node does not eval and become visible.

even though your console gave you :

```
truthy? : 1
```

What is going on here and what is the best approach?

Comment: do you have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` set on your component or on any parent component definition?

Comment: It's actually advisable to have it for performance reasons

Comment: It should work, I don't understand your issue

Comment: I made my own answer. My api being called at the contructor / oninit phase was the issue. Ideally I'd like to call it as soon as possible, but this means my evaled ngIfs are altered at points in it's lifecycle that Angular does not appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is changeDetect is for all intents and purposes OFF during an ngOnInit lifecycle. (and you should consider it OFF for things that come before as well such as the constructor)

Only at the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle does the changeDetect start back up.

By calling my API within ngAfterViewInit I have a correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Just to mention another possible solution.

Its also tipical to do:

```js
someObservable$ = this.http.post(
          this.url,
          args,
          this.authenticationService.getRequestOptions()
);

// or if getRequestOptions() somehow returns an observable:

someObservable$ = this.authenticationService.getRequestOptions().pipe(
    mergeMap((options) => {
        return this.http.post(this.url, args, options);
    })
);
```

```html
<div *ngIf="(someObservable$ | async)?.length">
    Don't show me until I'm ready please !
</div>
```

Beware that several things might be missing from this example snippet, **like avoiding multiple (Post) requests being done**.

Comment: @tatsu In my example, someObservable$ has no subscribe on purpose. The pipe async in the template already makes that subscribe implicitly.

Comment: Oh i see you placed subscribe in getRequestOptions(). You didnt have it in your original question code so I can only assume it was not needed (not an observable).